# how to display subtitles for a video?

Tags: video, subtitles

Recently, I have downloaded some Ted talks (`.flv` and mp4) with subtitles (`.srt` files), I put the video and subtitle file in same folder but when play video the subtitle doesn't display, I am using jetAudio and Windows Media Player.  (this first time I have used subtitles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename the subtitles exactly as the video file. For example,

> video.mp4
>   video.srt

and try again.

Regarding video player, I recommend [GOM Player](http://www.gomlab.com/eng/GMP_Introduction.html).

Answer (score 4):

You should try [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/). You'll have the option there under Video> Subtitles track

Comment: +1 for VLC.  Rocks, plays just about any video, and wide range of subtitle support.  Just make sure the filename part has the same name, just the different extensions